# How to sync Firestore database and Firebase Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a simple banking app with flutter.I'm creating the user login information myself and trying to auth them with firebase. I already coded the authentication part of the app.Here is the code:

```
import 'package:banking_app_firebase/screens/customers_info.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud_nsn/modal_progress_hud_nsn.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool showSpinner = false;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: showSpinner,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/662/662622.png",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration:
                    kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: "Enter your password"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                child: Material(
                  elevation: 5,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = true;
                      });
                      try {
                        final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: email!, password: password!);
                        if (user != null) {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, CustomerScreen.id);
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          showSpinner = true;
                        });
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                    height: 42,
                    child: Text(
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Sample Users:

[image]

However, I don't know how to sync these information with my database so I can reach the data in the database. Here is my example database:

[image]

How can I get the informations about customers like name,surname,balance after auth is successful? I mean, how can I tell the Firebase, the auth email and password same as firestore database?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the information about customers like
> name, surname, balance after auth is successful?

I understand that you want to link one document of the `customers` collection to each user. The classical solution to do so is to use the user `uid` as the Firestore document ID.

As soon as your user is created, you can get its [`uid`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/uid.html) and create the Firestore document, like, for example:

```
final user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email!, password: password!
);
if (user != null) {
    await addCustomer(user.uid, email, password);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, CustomerScreen.id);
}


...


CollectionReference customers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers');

Future<void> addCustomer(userID, email, password) {
  return customers
    .doc(userID)
    .set({
      ...
    })
    .then((value) => print("Customer added"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add customer: $error"));
}
```

---

I understand from your comment below that you want to query the `customers` collection to find the user which has a specific email and password.

This is possible with a [query](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying), however I would recommend not using the password value for executing queries. This is a sensitive data that you should avoid using as a query parameter.

Actually you can very well query just by email: since you cannot create two Firebase users with the same email, you are sure that your query will return a unique result (if you didn't create some duplicate documents in the `customers` collection...).

Comment: I already created users for authentication and database. What I want to do is, when a user logged in, I mean with firebase authentication, I wanted to show the informations who has the same email and password with authenticated user in database. I don't know if I could explain.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: I mean let's say I want to get the name variable as a string where 'email' = email. How can I get this value as a string? ` var name = customers.where('email', isEqualTo: email).get().then();` I tried this, but I think I did not how to reach that data.

Comment: Look at the doc on [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querysnapshot). Have also a look at this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40) from the [Firebase Tips & Tricks Medium publication](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks).